# Bootstrap 4 alpha how to add a drop-down menu to navigation?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is from Bootstrap v4 Alpha [blog theme](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/#). And I'm using this for a project. Then I tried to add a drop-down menu to this navigation bar as normal but the navigation bar dropdowns are not coming and not showing.

This is the drop-down, I tried to add to this navigation. But it's not working. Is this something I have to change from custom styles? Any input would be appreciated.

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  html {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #555;
}

h1, .h1,
h2, .h2,
h3, .h3,
h4, .h4,
h5, .h5,
h6, .h6 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
}


/*
 * Override Bootstrap's default container.
 */

.container {
  max-width: 60rem;
}


/*
 * Masthead for nav
 */

.blog-masthead {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  background-color: #428bca;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -.1rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 -.1rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* Nav links */
.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #cdddeb;
}
.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.nav-link.active {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-link.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -.3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border-right: .3rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: .3rem solid;
  border-left: .3rem solid transparent;
}


/*
 * Blog name and description
 */

.blog-header {
  padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-bottom: .05rem solid #eee;
}
.blog-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.blog-description {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #999;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  .blog-title {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}


/*
 * Main column and sidebar layout
 */

/* Sidebar modules for boxing content */
.sidebar-module {
  padding: 1rem;
  /*margin: 0 -1rem 1rem;*/
}
.sidebar-module-inset {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}
.sidebar-module-inset p:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ul:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ol:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Pagination */
.blog-pagination {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.blog-pagination > .btn {
  border-radius: 2rem;
}


/*
 * Blog posts
 */

.blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.blog-post-title {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.blog-post-meta {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  color: #999;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.blog-footer {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: .05rem solid #e5e5e5;
}
.blog-footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/blog/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav blog-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">New features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Press</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">New hires</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description">An example blog template built with Bootstrap.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
```

Comment: Can you post all of the HTML? Also, you're not using alpha like the example so it's going to work differently

Comment: I'm using this exact theme. But there are no examples there, using dropdown menus in that theme. I tried to add as normal but couldn't make it work. ps . I'm still learning to code :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a drop-down in Bootstrap 4 should look like (note: this is Bootstrap 4 release version; the alpha version is outdated):

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The `dropdown-item` classes are missing in your code.

Here's a full navbar example for Bootstrap 4, including a drop-down:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work with the theme I listed on top. :( It's showing weirdly.

Comment: That's because you aren't loading Bootstrap 4. The alpha version is outdated.

Comment: Also, there are no drop-downs anywhere in that theme that you are linking to.

Comment: Tks. Never knew that. So that means we can not add dropdown to this navigation bar?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a full navbar example that includes a working drop-down example. Use that as a starting point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167201/discussion-between-rashmi-nimesha-and-webdevbooster).